# What is the easiest way to reformat paragraphs to a certain width in emacs?

Tags: emacs

For Vim users: I'm looking for the equivalence of `tw=80`, `gq`

I have two paragraphs of a certain width, which I'd like to reformat to fit in the width of 80 characters. What is the easiest way to do that, while keeping the paragraphs (empty line between) separate?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

80 characters should be the default width, otherwise:

```
C-x f 80 RET
```

Then select your paragraphs and press:

```
M-q
```

For the justified version use:

```
M-1 M-q
```

Where `M` is the meta key: <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Comment: 80 was just an example. In any case, works perfectly, thanks cYrus!

Comment: Btw, does emacs have a command to restore the last selection again? (so I don't have to go any select the region manually over and over)?

Comment: I don't know, but if it concerns paragraph reformatting consider the following: 1) `M-q` will be applied to the current paragraph if nothing else is selected; 2) you can `M-x auto-fill-mode` to automatically reformat text as you write it. Hope this helps.

Comment: It does somewhat, yup :)

Comment: @Idigas: If you didn't move you can use `C-x C-x` to `exchange-point-and-mark` and thus reselect the last region. If you've moved, the last region will be selected extended to your current position.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent the reformatting to preserve multiple spaces between words? It does not only adjust the width, it changes also any multiple spaces to one space ...